# PHP - Form that sends to URL in the server

Tags: php, forms

i have a question about PHP, i don´t know if this is possible. 
I want to have a form, something like this:

```
<form action="myfile.php" method="post">
Video URL: <input type="text" name="vidurl"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and i would like that whatever URL that is entered in the text field "vidurl", opens up in the host, for example.

Video URL: (textfield): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TESTVIDEO 
When they click submit, the video opens up in the host, also, i would like it to have a timer. For example, open video for 5 seconds, and then close it, then open it again and close it.
Can someone help me with this? thanks.

Comment: You probably just want `myfile.php` to contain a `<iframe src="THE_POSTED_VIDEO_URL"></iframe>` – you can show/hide it whenever you like using Javascript

Comment: By opens up in the host you mean that on the server you want to start a new browser process and open a youtube video?

Comment: You want a popup with the adress? Then just use Javascript with window.open() function.

Comment: @Bagonyi yes that is what i mean

Comment: @MarcelBalzer no what i want is that a youtube video opens up in the hosting, and refreshes itself for example every 5 seconds,

Comment: @Shai but does it load with the host/server IP Address?.

Comment: @KnightScript no, the request to e.g. YouTube would originate from the client's IP address. If you need it to come from your server (you're effectively writing a proxy service), Google for *how to make a proxy server* or similar. Or take a look at PHP's `cURL` functions.

Comment: @Shai You mean i would need to make a kind of proxy service?.

Comment: I have no idea what you need to make, you haven't said whether you want the request to be sent from the server IP or client IP.

Comment: Alright, here goes long description:
I need a form, that they write a URL of youtube, and my server will visit that site, if it is possible, the video will refresh itself every 5 - 10 seconds,

Comment: possible, your php will need to use proc_open() or the Symfony Process Component to open a browser (eg. Chrome) process and open up that URL. As for the every 5 sec refresh.. You could open up your own html in which you pass the url as a get parameter and there you have a javascript which refreshes the page every 5 second. A bit complicated :)

Comment: @bagonyi oh, alright, is the code very large?. Maybe you can help me out with it :D at least the hard part, which is the proc_open() thing... Please?, or can you send me the tutorial, Thanks.

Comment: On which OS will you host this script? Windows?

Comment: It would be Linux CentOS 6.4 KVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exec('/path/to/Chrome ' . $_POST['vidurl']);
```

This should execute Chrome with your page open. If you want to have this page refreshed every X sec, you would need to create a html file locally. Haven't tested, but you might be after something like this:

myfile.php:

```
exec('/path/to/Chrome file:///path/to/page-refresher.html?url=' . $_POST['vidurl']);
```

page-refresher.html

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
      <iframe id="iframe"></iframe>

      <script>
          window.onload = function () {
              var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
              iframe.src = window.location.search.replace('?url=', '');

              iframe.onload = function () {
                  window.setTimeout(
                      function () {
                          window.location.reload();
                      }, 
                      5000
                  );
              };
          };
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

To list all running processes, you need to exec the ps command:

```
exec('ps aux', $output);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, one question, if i need to add a restriction timer, for example, i dont want people to send more than 100 refreshes every 10 minutes, is there a way to implement this? Thank you

Comment: also i would like to know how can i see the current tasks, not using ssh "TOP"